Unable to get Azure Document Intelligence service to process a 1000pg. PDF
I can't find any information on this. Currently using a Premium App Service Plan-hosted Azure Function with functionTimeout set to 00:30:00 but still timing out.
PDF specs:

1000 pages
30MiB
Scanned documents, no text

Here is the DocIntel function:
from azure.ai.documentintelligence.aio import DocumentIntelligenceClient
from azure.ai.documentintelligence.models import AnalyzeDocumentRequest


async def create_doc_intel_client(credential):
    
    doc_intel_endpoint = f'https://{DOC_INTEL_RESOURCE}.cognitiveservices.azure.com'
    
    try:
        doc_intel_client = DocumentIntelligenceClient(
                                doc_intel_endpoint,
                                credential)
        logging.info(f'#### Doc Intel Client Successfully Created')
        
        return doc_intel_client
    
    except Exception as e:
        logging.error(f'#### Failed to create Doc Intel Client: {e}')

        raise


async def get_doc_layout(doc_client, doc_url):
    try:
        async with doc_client:
            poller = await doc_client.begin_analyze_document(
                "prebuilt-layout",
                AnalyzeDocumentRequest(url_source=doc_url)
            )
            
            minutes_elapsed = 0
            while not poller.done():
                status = poller.status()
                logging.info(f'#### Polling status: {status} | Minutes elapsed: {minutes_elapsed}')
                await asyncio.sleep(60)  # Sleep for 60 seconds (1 minute)
                minutes_elapsed += 1

            doc_analysis = await poller.result()
            doc_analysis_dict = doc_analysis.as_dict()
            doc_analysis_json = json.dumps(doc_analysis_dict)

            logging.info(f'#### Document successfully analyzed')

            return doc_analysis_json
    
    except Exception as e:
        logging.error(f'#### Failed to analyze document: {e}')
        raise

Logs:
2024-05-26T17:21:12Z   [Information]   #### Polling status: InProgress | Minutes elapsed: 1
2024-05-26T17:22:12Z   [Information]   #### Polling status: InProgress | Minutes elapsed: 2
2024-05-26T17:23:12Z   [Information]   #### Polling status: InProgress | Minutes elapsed: 3
2024-05-26T17:24:12Z   [Information]   #### Polling status: InProgress | Minutes elapsed: 4
2024-05-26T17:25:12Z   [Information]   #### Polling status: InProgress | Minutes elapsed: 5
2024-05-26T17:26:12Z   [Information]   #### Polling status: InProgress | Minutes elapsed: 6
2024-05-26T17:27:12Z   [Information]   #### Polling status: InProgress | Minutes elapsed: 7
2024-05-26T17:28:13Z   [Information]   #### Polling status: InProgress | Minutes elapsed: 8
2024-05-26T17:29:13Z   [Information]   #### Polling status: InProgress | Minutes elapsed: 9
2024-05-26T17:30:13Z   [Information]   #### Polling status: InProgress | Minutes elapsed: 10
2024-05-26T17:31:13Z   [Information]   #### Polling status: InProgress | Minutes elapsed: 11
2024-05-26T17:32:13Z   [Information]   #### Polling status: InProgress | Minutes elapsed: 12
2024-05-26T17:33:13Z   [Information]   #### Polling status: InProgress | Minutes elapsed: 13
2024-05-26T17:34:13Z   [Information]   #### Polling status: InProgress | Minutes elapsed: 14
2024-05-26T17:35:13Z   [Information]   #### Polling status: InProgress | Minutes elapsed: 15
2024-05-26T17:36:13Z   [Information]   #### Polling status: InProgress | Minutes elapsed: 16
2024-05-26T17:37:13Z   [Information]   #### Polling status: InProgress | Minutes elapsed: 17
2024-05-26T17:38:13Z   [Information]   #### Polling status: InProgress | Minutes elapsed: 18
2024-05-26T17:39:13Z   [Information]   #### Polling status: InProgress | Minutes elapsed: 19
2024-05-26T17:40:13Z   [Information]   #### Polling status: InProgress | Minutes elapsed: 20
2024-05-26T17:41:13Z   [Information]   #### Polling status: InProgress | Minutes elapsed: 21
2024-05-26T17:42:13Z   [Information]   #### Polling status: InProgress | Minutes elapsed: 22
2024-05-26T17:43:13Z   [Information]   #### Polling status: InProgress | Minutes elapsed: 23
2024-05-26T17:44:13Z   [Information]   #### Polling status: InProgress | Minutes elapsed: 24
2024-05-26T17:45:13Z   [Information]   #### Polling status: InProgress | Minutes elapsed: 25
2024-05-26T17:46:13Z   [Information]   #### Polling status: InProgress | Minutes elapsed: 26
2024-05-26T17:47:13Z   [Information]   #### Polling status: InProgress | Minutes elapsed: 27
2024-05-26T17:48:13Z   [Information]   #### Polling status: InProgress | Minutes elapsed: 28
2024-05-26T17:49:13Z   [Information]   #### Polling status: InProgress | Minutes elapsed: 29
2024-05-26T17:50:11Z   [Error]   Timeout value of 00:30:00 exceeded by function 'Functions.doc-process' (Id: '<guid>'). Initiating cancellation.
2024-05-26T17:50:11Z   [Error]   Executed 'Functions.doc-process' (Failed, Id=<guid>, Duration=1799999ms)

Update 1:

Set functionTimeout: -1
Let the Function run for 90 mins, still no response.


Upgraded the Function App and set functionTimeout to -1. I let it go 90 mins then cancelled... DocIntel has a stated capacity / request of 2000 pages, but... if it takes longer than...10-20 mins, maybe more viable to split the PDF into smaller chunks?

Hm...the DocIntel poller just says InProgress and never returns a value. Please see above function. Maybe I'm missing something? The PDF is 1000 pages and 30MiB.

The PDF has no text, its all scanned document images.
